# Why would Azure AD SAML SSO be stuck (greyed out) on SHA-1?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm attempting to build SAML SSO in Azure AD for an external app. If I try to create a signing certificate, or import a .pfx that I know was created with SHA256, Azure does not allow the selection of SHA256. The option is greyed out and stuck on SHA-1. The Azure AD tenant is part of a large organization. Could this be a global option or something specific to the tenant itself that is limiting this option? Thank you!

[image: Signing Algorithm Greyed Out]

Comment: Do you still face the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same but was able to select any of both  signing algorithm options.

[image]

Thought it was due to expiry date having need to be between three years from uploading as said in this [Manage federation certificates - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-certificates-for-federated-single-sign-on#customize-the-expiration-date-for-your-federation-certificate-and-roll-it-over-to-a-new-certificate) .And checked  uploading a new certificate with expiry 2031 and with both algorithms sha-256 and sha-1 each time  but still was able to get the options for algorithm successfully.

Possible causes:

1. Older ASA versions may not support SHA-256 cert presented by Azure
2. Please check if the certificate is uploaded with required algorithm and check by changing expiration date.
3. Sometimes it may be due to changes taking time to effect in portal .Retry after giving it sometime by closing all.
4. Incorrect Configuration properties might also be the cause.

Otherwise you can raise a support request from **Overview page > Troubleshooting + Support >New support request.**

**References:**

1. [Azure SAML Implementation | Bitwarden Help & Support](https://bitwarden.com/help/article/saml-azure/#identity-provider-configuration)
2. [Change signature hash algorithm for Microsoft 365 relying party trust - Azure | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-sha256-guidance#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20AD%20FS%20management%20console%20on%20the,select%20the%20secure%20hash%20algorithm%20SHA256.%20Click%20OK.)
3. [Configure ASA AnyConnect VPN with Microsoft Azure MFA through SAML - Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/215935-configure-asa-anyconnect-vpn-with-micros.html)